# Sharing local SSH key with pgadmin4 docker container; permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I have troubles finding a way to share my local SSH keys to the [pgadmin4 docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/).

Here is how I proceed, by mounting my `~/.ssh` folder into the container:

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.5
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=email@domain.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=********
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - ~/.ssh:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/postgres_local.host/.ssh
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  pgadmin-data: {}
```

Then, when setting up a connection, in the "SSH Tunnel" tab, I click the three little dots in front of the "Identify file" option:

[image]

But then, when browsing for an SSH key file, that bind folder has a small "lock" icon attached to it, and indeed, I got a "Permission denied" error when I try to open it:

[image]

Hence my question: what's the best and most convenient way to safely share some SSH identity files with that container?
Is it a good idea to do so?
Please note that they are obviously chmoded `600` on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is almost certainly related to permissions and I've managed to get my SSH tunnel to work by running the pgAdmin container as `root`.

This can be done by adding the `user: root` property to your service in Docker Compose file, e.g.:

```
services:
  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    user: root
    # other properties here
```

Please note, running Docker containers as superuser comes with security risks so use this approach with caution.

*This has been tested on an M1 Mac since the native pgAdmin 4 application is not yet available for this architecture.*